# Quantum algorithm to get $d$ (private exponent) directly without factoring first

Tags: complexity-theory, shors-algorithm

Shor's algorithm is for finding period $r$ such that $a^r\equiv 1\bmod N$. Knowing  period we can factor $N$.

In RSA we encrypt message $m$ by $m^e\bmod N$ ($e$ and $N$ are public keys).

Let us pick the message (and so we know $m$) and encrypt to get $y\equiv m^e\bmod N$.

Can Shor's algorithm be modified to get $d$ (the private decryption key) directly such that $y^d\equiv m\bmod N$ without factoring $N$? (the equation $y^d\equiv m\bmod N$ looks similar to $a^r\equiv 1\bmod N$)

If so, is there any advantage in terms of the number of qubits needed?

To clarify: I want to learn $d$ before learning any other information which will factor on a classical computer in $BPTIME$. Casting the problem as a discrete logarithm problem requires knowledge of order of $m$ which already factors $N$ without finding $d$. I want to find $d$ without knowing other information which can factor $N$ before learning $d$.

Answer (score 3):

First, welcome to the quantum stack exchange. Please find below an answer, in two parts:

1. Given $m \in \mathbb Z_N^*$ and $y = m^e$, computing $d$ so that $m = y^d$ is the discrete logarithm problem (DLP).

   Shor's quantum algorithm for the DLP — that is also described in [[Shor94]](https://doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1994.365700) alongside Shor's order-finding and factoring algorithms — solves this problem (when slightly generalized as in e.g. [[E19p]](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1905.09084) to work in the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb Z_N^*$ that is generated by $m$).

   However, it is not more efficient than Shor's order-finding algorithm.
   Furthermore, it requires the order $r$ of $m$ to be known, and if you know $r$ or a multiple thereof then you can factor $N$ classically (with probability very close to one via [[E21b]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11128-021-03069-1), provided that you select $m$ uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_N^*$ at the outset, and this is easy).

   Another possible option is of course to compute the order $r$ of $m$, or a multiple thereof, and to use that $d \equiv e^{-1} \text{ mod } r$, if this is what you are looking for? This would not save qubits. It may perhaps save runs when using Shor's original reduction, but not when using [[E21b]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11128-021-03069-1). Yet another option is to use the variation in [[E21a]](https://doi.org/10.1515/jmc-2020-0006) that computes $d$ without requiring $r$ to be known beforehand, but this variation is also less efficient (and it in fact computes both $d$ and $r$ even if you need not explicitly compute $r$ in the post-processing to compute $d$). In short, I think that this all boils down to a question of semantics, because once you learn $d$, you know that $ed - 1$ is a multiple of $r$, and so you can use [[E21b]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11128-021-03069-1) to factor $N$ classically.
2. If you are looking to achieve an advantage by phrasing the RSA integer factoring problem (IFP) as a DLP, then you may instead wish to have a look at [[EH17]](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-59879-6_20). In this work, we pick $g$ uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_N^*$, for $N = pq$ a random RSA integer, compute
   $$x = g^{(N+1)/2} = g^{(p+q)/2},$$
   classically, and then compute the logarithm $d = \log_g x$ using a quantum algorithm that leverages that $d$ is short in relation to the order of $g$ with overwhelming probability, and which critically does not require the order to be known. With high probability of success, this algorithm yields $d = (p+q)/2$, and since we also know that $N = pq$ it is then trivial to solve for $p$ and $q$ classically.

   This DLP-based algorithm is more efficient than Shor's order finding-based approach [[E20]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10623-020-00783-2), but it only works for RSA integers (it can be extended to other special forms, but factoring RSA integers is arguably the interesting case).

(Note that $d$ in the second part of this answer is different from $d$ in the first part, and that the order $r$ of $m$ is also the order of $y$ by construction since $e$ is coprime to $\lambda(N)$ in RSA. Note also that $d$ in the first part of this answer would typically be on $[0, r)$, in which case $d$ is not the full private key, although it will decrypt $y$.)

Comment: I thought for Shor's discrete log algorithm modulo $N$, the factorization of $N$ has to be known. And so solving $y^d\equiv m\bmod N$ is not quite possible by Shor's algorithm for discrete log as factorization of $N$ is unknown. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Turbo You would need to know the order $r$ of $m$, but to compute $r$ classically without the complete factorization of $N$ is hard. You would also need the complete factorization of $p - 1$ for $p$ the prime factors of $N$. (If you had an efficient classical algorithm for computing $r$, then you could use it to factor $N$.)

Comment: So we cannot compute $d$ as discrete logarithm problem without factoring using your idea?

Comment: @Turbo Maybe without explicitly factoring $N$, if you count the "Another possible option (..)" paragraph in the first part of my answer as a valid solution? It depends on what you mean by "without factoring". Once you learn $d$, then $ed - 1$ is a multiple of the order $r$, and so you can factor $N$ completely via [E21b](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11128-021-03069-1).

Comment: I want to learn $d$ before learning any other information which will factor on a classical computer.

Comment: @Turbo Well, then maybe see the paragraph I referred you to above? But as I also wrote above, once you learn $d$ you have enough information to factor $N$ with very high probability of success classically, so it becomes a question of semantics.

Comment: @Turbo I added some more material now to said paragraph in my answer, following your clarification of your question.